# How to define a constructor template of a class template outside of the class template?

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

Consider the following:

```
template<typename R>
struct call {
    template<typename F, typename... Args>
    explicit call(F&& f, Args&&... args);

    R result;
};

template<typename R, typename F, typename... Args>
call<R>::call(F&& f, Args&&... args)
: result(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) { }
```

clang yells at me:

```
utility.tpp:40:1: error: too many template parameters in template redeclaration
template<typename R, typename F, typename... Args>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
utility.hpp:36:5: note: previous template declaration is here
    template<typename R>
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm absolutely puzzled. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need *two* templates: one for the class and one for the constructor:

```
template <typename R>                   // <== for call<R>
template <typename F, typename... Args> // <== for call(F&&, Args&&...)
call<R>::call(F&& f, Args&&... args)
```